# Trusted Root certificates regularly disappear on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security, certificate, trusted-root-ca

I've installed several self-signed certificates on my Windows 7 Ultimate x64 machine for development purposes. One was installed into Trusted Root CAs and 2 were installed into My Certificates and Trusted People. Every day or two the certificate installed into Trusted Root CAs disappears and I have to re-install it! This is annoying the hell out of me. Why is it happening and how do I stop it?

The other certificates (installed into other stores) do not disappear. My first thought was some kind of Group Policy, but my machine is not part of a domain - though it does obtains its IP address from a corporate DHCP server, so I'm not sure if they can somehow still manage to apply Group Policy to me.

Answer (score 9):

## "Root" store solved it

The solution was to install it into the `Root` store, which puts it under `Registry` (if you view physical stores in the Certificates snap-in), instead of the `AuthRoot` store, which puts it under `Third-Party`. I don't know why it was disappearing from `Third-Party`, but it hasn't happened since I made this change.

Thanks to [Charlie Wilson](https://superuser.com/questions/222206/trusted-root-certificates-regularly-disappear-on-windows-7/222212#222212) for pointing me in the right direction. I just wanted to type out the full answer in case anyone else had this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was going crazy after the third time my certificates went missing.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted solution

Comment: Its always something with Microsoft, never straightforward. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you choose where the certificates should be stored are you choosing a physical store such as Registry or Local Computer?  I am not sure what the problem is but I have always been successful with choosing Registry.  Good luck.

Comment: Interesting thought... The one that disappears is under "Third Party", while most are under "Registry". I might try installing it under "Registry" and see if that helps.